# Memory optimization in C for an array of 1 million records

Tags: c, optimization, memory

I am writing a program which requires me to create an array of a million records. The array indices are unique ids(0-million represents unique product id). At first all elements are initialized to zero. They are incremented depending upon product sold.

This approach however has a high space complexity (4 * million bytes). Later I saw that only certain products need frequent updating. So is there any way in which I can reduce memory usage as well as keep track of all the products?

Comment: 4 MB isn't very much...

Comment: You maybe want something like a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)?

Comment: i want to reduce the memory usage as low as possible.

Comment: @dbaupp you're not developing for the AVR platform, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need frequent updating then you can store all the results in a file. Whenever you are updating any entry you can just create a temp file with all the other entries plus the updated one. After that you can just change the name of the temp file using `rename(temp,new);`.

Although, an array of million records doesn't require that much memory(just 4 megabytes). So, your approach is the best and the easiest one.

The best approach(algorithmically) would be to make a hash table to store all the entries. But if you are not an expert in C then making a hash table could be a problem for you.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more like a situation for table in a database than an in-memory array to me. If your use case allows for it, I'd use a database instead.

Otherwise, if in your use case:

1. a significant fraction of the products will eventually be used,
2. RAM is limited,
3. external storage (disk, serial memory) is available,
4. average access performance comparable to RAM speeds is required, and
5. increased worst case access time is acceptable,

then you could try some sort of caching scheme (lru maybe?). This will use more code space, somewhat increase your average access time, and more significantly increase your worst case access time.

If a large fraction of the products will not just be infrequently, but never used, then you should look into @fatrock92's suggestion of a hash table.

Answer (score 0):

It's better use dynamic allocation of memory for array.
use of malloc or realloc can give you better way to allocate memory 
I think you know how to use malloc and realloc

Answer (score 0):

You can use [link list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list), so whenever you need you can add or update elements in your list.
Also you can hold last time access in each node so you'd able to remove the nodes that has not been used lately.